# A series query on groupby function

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a data frame called `active` and it has 10 unique `POS` column values. 
[image] Then I group `POS` values and mean normalize the OPW columns and then store the normalized values as a seperate column `['resid']`. 
[image] If I groupby on `POS` values shouldnt the new active data frame's `POS` columns contain only unique `POS` values??

For example:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'X' : ['B', 'B', 'A', 'A'], 'Y' : [1, 2, 3, 4]})
print df2

df2.groupby(['X']).sum()
```

I get an output like this:

```
    Y
X   
A   7
B   3
```

In my example shouldn't I get an column with only unique Pos values as mentioned below??

**POS**     **Other Columns** 
Rf             values 
2B              values 
LF             values 
2B              values 
OF             values

Comment: please post some test data instead of images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't be 100% sure without the actual data, but i'm pretty sure that the problem here is that you are not aggregating the data.

Let's go through the groupby step by step.

When you do `active.groupby('POS')`, what's actually happening is that you are slicing the dataframe per each unique POS, and passing each of these sclices, sequentially, to the applied function.

You can get a better vision of what's happening by using get_group (ex : active.groupby('POS').get_group('RF') )

So you're applying your `meanNormalizeOPW` function to each of those slices. That function creates a mean normalized value of the column 'resid' **for each line of the passed dataframe**. And you return that dataframe, ending with a shape that is similar than what was passed.

So if you just add an aggregation function to the returned df, it should work fine. I guess here you want a mean, so just change `return df` into `return df.mean()`

Comment: Nice explanation, but you said that you are passing uniques POS values right?? But in this case I have just 10 uniques POS values, then I should get some thing as discussed in my example.

Comment: No, it's not passing the unique pos values. It s passing a slice of the dataframe containing all the lines containing one POS. Try running the get_group to get a better feeling of how it works.

Comment: active.groupby('POS').get_group('RF') I am getting a key error. I am not able to use this on my data frame. But for 2B it is working. Ok thanks I got the basic idea behind the concept. More over, I dont think we have to return df.mean() in  meanNormalizeOPW function.